# Best words to indicate appreciate/depreciate instead of like/dislike

Tags: copywriting, wording

we have designed a system that creates a personalized stream of (text based) content for users. In order for the system to adapt, the users have to constantly give some feedback based on whether a piece of content matches their personal taste and interests/topics they've pre-selected.

The explicit feedback is given by two buttons whereas the call-to-action for each one until now, was "Interesting" and "Not Interesting". We're thinking however that a piece of content might be interesting to the user but not necessarily in accordance to the current topic of the stream or the user's real interests and favors. Maybe I should also add that these two buttons have a secondary meaning too. The positive feedback rewards the owner of the content while the negative doesn't. The user is familiar with this rewarding concept, but still it's secondary to him since the relevance of the content feedback is top priority.

We don't like: like/dislike

We thought of: Relevant/Not Relevant but might cause confusion like "relevant to what?"

We thought of: Worthy/Not Worthy but maybe too strict.

Any other thoughts and discussion would be highly appreciated folks.

Answer (score 5):

Do you really have to put words to it. Why dont you just have up and down buttons like here in stackexchange, or a + - button.

That will easily convey what you want and also you wont be trapped into words.

Comment: (+) and (-) as well as ^ and v would definitely work for something like incremental feedback. However this is an on/off and one-off situation.

Comment: Pertinent / Impertinent

Or a tick button in green and a cross in red can also work perfectly for your case of on/off (which also includes a hint of like/dislike).

Comment: Thumbs up/down works fine for Pandora. You may be overthinking this...

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but it's often difficult to describe this action using a verb.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to use smiley face / sad face.

Smiley face alone should work just fine too, to help people mark the ones that they like. Nobody searches for the ones that are most disliked, they want the ones that have been marked with a smiley face the most time.

It's pretty hard to find something new with words. It's like finding a new word for starting a movie instead of "play". Facebook and Youtube have done a great job making like/dislike a standard.

Answer (score 0):

In Germanys Business Network they use.

Interesting as a like.
So perhaps: Interesting / Not interesting

Comment: Interesting/Not Interesting is what we already have.

Answer (score 0):

What about diferent positive feedback (medals or tags) and a dropdown with negative reasons they can give?
Wikipedia use medals for quality content. Diferent medals could be: interesting, must read, trustworthy, recommend, complete, etc
Meneame is a reference you can research in negative feedbacks.